# Yearly tax calendar for my S-Corporation: What tax forms are due on what dates?

Tags: united-states, taxes, s-corporation

I'd like to create a document that's basically a yearly tax calendar for my S-Corporation. My accountant handles my taxes, but she is completely disorganized and it drives me insane. Basically what I want is to know what tax forms need to be filed, and on what dates?

Please don't link to IRS websites – I'm not looking to read through a million pages of government documents to figure this out.

I have a single employee S-Corporation from which I pay a payroll. I pay estimated taxes quarterly, so I'm usually dealing with form 941 when I pay. I have also seen her give me form 940, and a few other forms I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

> My accountant handles my taxes, but she is completely disorganized and it drives me insane.

That's her job to keep track of the dates for you. If she can't do it - find another accountant.

> Please don't link to IRS websites – I'm not looking to read through a
>   million pages of government documents to figure this out.

While understandable, its unacceptable. If you don't want to have your accountant do that - you'll **have to** read through a million of pages of government documents to figure this out.

Each tax form has its own schedule requirements. The main one for income tax is 1120S, which is filed 2 and a half months after your tax year ends. The other two important ones are 940 and 941 filed quarterly and yearly.

If you're incapable of going through the IRS website and reading the instructions - **do not do it on your own**. If your accountant is incapable of providing you with the required services - find another one.